Gaussian pulses in frequency domain
I have successfully generated Gaussian pulses (as shown in the top graph) using the equation in the provided screenshot via a Python script. However, the spectrum I obtained is not similar to the one in the bottom graph. I need guidance to produce a similar spectral graph.
The sampling time, Δt, is 1.0 μs.


Used Python code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
import csv

def generate_gaussian_pulse(T, dt, amplitude=1.0):
    """
    Generate a single Gaussian pulse in the time domain.
    """
    t = np.arange(0, T, dt)
    gp = amplitude * np.exp(-((t - T / 2) / (0.29 * T)) ** 2)
    return t, gp

def generate_multiple_gaussian_pulses(T, dt, amplitude, num_pulses, pulse_spacing):
    """
    Generate multiple Gaussian pulses.
    """
    t_total = []
    gp_total = []
    for i in range(num_pulses):
        t, gp = generate_gaussian_pulse(T, dt, amplitude)
        t += i * (T + pulse_spacing)  # Shift each pulse in time
        t_total.extend(t)
        gp_total.extend(gp)
    return np.array(t_total), np.array(gp_total)

def analyze_frequency(t, gp, sampling_rate):
    """
    Perform FFT to analyze the frequency characteristics of the pulse.
    """
    N = len(gp)
    freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(N, d=1 / sampling_rate)
    fft_values = np.fft.rfft(gp)
    amplitude_spectrum = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(fft_values) / np.max(np.abs(fft_values)))  # in dB
    return freq, amplitude_spectrum

def apply_low_pass_filter(signal, cutoff, sampling_rate, order=4):
    """
    Apply a low-pass Butterworth filter to the signal.
    """
    nyquist = 0.5 * sampling_rate
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyquist
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    filtered_signal = filtfilt(b, a, signal)
    return filtered_signal

# Parameters
T = 0.0000646  # Pulse duration in seconds (140 μs)
dt = 0.000001  # Time step (100 ns for high resolution)
amplitude = 1.0  # Peak amplitude in Pascals
sampling_rate = 1 / dt  # Sampling rate (Hz)
cutoff_frequency = 9000  # Low-pass filter cutoff frequency (10 kHz)
num_pulses = 387 # Number of pulses
pulse_spacing = 0  # Time spacing between pulses (in seconds)

# Generate multiple Gaussian pulses
t, gp = generate_multiple_gaussian_pulses(T, dt, amplitude, num_pulses, pulse_spacing)

# Apply low-pass filter
filtered_gp = apply_low_pass_filter(gp, cutoff_frequency, sampling_rate)

# Analyze frequency domain
freq, amplitude_spectrum = analyze_frequency(t, gp, sampling_rate)
freq_filtered, amplitude_spectrum_filtered = analyze_frequency(t, filtered_gp, sampling_rate)

# Plot Gaussian pulses in time domain
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

# Original pulses
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t * 1e6, gp, label="Original Gaussian Pulses")
plt.xlabel("Time (μs)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude (Pa)")
plt.title("(a) Original Gaussian Pulses")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

# Filtered pulses
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t * 1e6, filtered_gp, label="Filtered Pulses (10 kHz cutoff)", color="orange")
plt.xlabel("Time (μs)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude (Pa)")
plt.title("(b) Filtered Gaussian Pulses")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

# Frequency characteristics
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(freq / 1e3, amplitude_spectrum, label="Original Spectrum")
plt.plot(freq_filtered / 1e3, amplitude_spectrum_filtered, label="Filtered Spectrum", linestyle="--", color="orange")
plt.xlabel("Frequency (kHz)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude (dB)")
plt.title("(c) Frequency Characteristics")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Export data to CSV
with open("gaussian_pulses.csv", mode="w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Time (s)", "Original Amplitude (Pa)", "Filtered Amplitude (Pa)"])
    for time, orig_amp, filt_amp in zip(t, gp, filtered_gp):
        writer.writerow([time, orig_amp, filt_amp])

